# Passing Json to the view in c# mvc

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, knockout.js

I am displaying the data from the table using knockout JS. But there is showing "The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[KnockOutDemo.Models.State]'." error.

Here is my js code as KOIndex.js

```
$(function () {
    ko.applyBindings(modelView);
    modelView.viewStates();
});

var modelView = {
    States = ko.observableArray([]),
    viewStates: function () {
        var thisobj = this;
        try {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/State/Index',
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                success: function (data) {
                    thisObj.States(data);
                },  
                error: function (err) {
                    alert(err.status + " : " + err.statusText);
                }
            });
        }
        catch (e) {
            window.location.href = '/State/Index';
        }
    }
};
```

Controller file

```
public class StateController : Controller
{
    private Database1Entities db = new Database1Entities();

    // GET: State
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(Json(db.States.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet));

    }
}
```

Index.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<KnockOutDemo.Models.State>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
<tr>
    <th>
        State Name
    </th>
    <th>Action</th>
</tr>

<tbody data-bind="foreach : States">
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="text : StateName"></td>
        <td>
            <a data-bind="attr : { 'href' : '@Url.Action("Edit", "State")/' + StateID }" class="btn-link">Edit</a>
            <a data-bind="attr: { 'href': '@Url.Action("Delete", "Home")/' + StateID }" class="btn-link">Delete</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/Knockout/K?OIndex.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/knockout-3.5.0.js"></script>
```

Comment: *Don't* pass JSON to the view. Or don't use a model. The `@model IEnumerable<KnockOutDemo.Models.State>` statement you used says that you'll pass an `IEnumerable<KnockOutDemo.Models.State>`, not a string. You don't need to pass JSON anyway - the view isn't something that runs on another machine, it's the template used by the web app to generate HTML. Just write `return View(db.States.ToList());`

Comment: On the other hand, if you want your *Knockout* code to call to a web service and get back a JSON string with the data, don't return anything. Write a *different* API controller that retuns the data as JSON, eg with `return JSon(db.States.ToList())`. The HTML/Javascript code in your view should call that HTTP endpoint to fetch the data and bind it to the table, controls.